# Getting attribute of a child element

Tags: jquery

How may I get the attribut of h3 child `li` ?

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h3> Element 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li data-id="5">Element 1.1</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on H3, how may I get the `data-id` from the child li ? I tried to use `JQuery.child()` and `JQuery.find()` but did not work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(event){
        var obj = event.target; //H3 here

        //First attempt:  1º child = ul   |   2º child = li
        $(obj).child().child().attr('data-id');
       //Second attempt:
       $(obj).find("li").attr('data-id');

    })
})
```

Is there a better and more correct way to do this  ?

Comment: The li is technically not a child of the h3. It's more of a child of an adjacent node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the `li` you are targeting is a descendant of the next sibling of the `h3`.

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to find a descendant of the calling element, but in this case the target element is not a descendant of the `h3`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).next().find('li').data('id');
    snippet.log('id: ' + id)
  })
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3> Element 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li data-id="5">Element 1.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy =) Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.next()` method allows you to query the next element in the DOM matching a particular selector. This is especially useful when the element you're looking for is not necessarily a descendent.

So if you have a reference to the h3 element in the click event handler as `this`, you could do `$(this).next('li').data('id')`.

Aside: There's no need for `.find()` to query for the element all over again; you can simply query the li element in the `.next()` step.

More info on `.next()`: https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: I tried this `var id = $(this).next('li').data('id'); console.log(id)` and console.log returned me `Undefined`.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro what is the value of this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the next element of `h3` and you got `ul`, then find it child by using `.find()`, use following code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("h3").click(function(event){        
     $(this).next().find("li").data('id');

   })
 })
```